# Combine multiple text input box's

Tags: javascript, html, css, textinput

So I have 3 text input areas. The reason for this because I need a black line separating each line of text.

[image: Black lines separating each line]

I need to figure out a way to make these text box's feel as one huge text area.

i.e. - As you type it moves to the next line when there is no more space left, when you delete text it push's it back to the previous line if needed.

Does anyone know any work arounds or ways I can achieve this?

---

I basically need to make a box that people can type in that looks exactly like the picture, but people can only type and edit in the blue area. The text "Label of what people will type." can NOT be changed, edited, deleted, etc.

Comment: Wrong way to do stuff. Use a textarea. Any reason you find hundreds of inputs better than a single textarea?

Comment: Text area's are usually square. From the above picture, I need to have the text area indented on the first line because of the label. @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @bryan: are you going to spend several days to implement every behavior with text being inserted, deleted moved, cut&paste... I say this is wrong on so many levels. Are you trying to emulate a paper form or what?

Comment: @some I am emulating a form that has to look a certain way. I don't mind trying got use a text area instead. I know that will be easier. It just NEEDS to have that label on the first line. The only way I could see that working and having an non square text area is with input box's instead. I am open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: @brian I really don't understand from your picture what you mean by "indented"

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I basically need to make a box that people can type in that looks exactly like the picture, but people can only type and edit in the blue area. Notice how "Label of what people will type." is on the first line where the text area will also start. However, on the next line, the text area continues underneathe where the label started and not where the text area started.

Comment: Seems like the wrong approach for this. I would use a div overlay to place lines over the text area. If you create them seperatly as you're proposing anybody trying to copy-past into the field(s) is going to be pretty upset with you.

Comment: @bryan Have a look at my answer below. It uses one textarea, first line indented, with lines for each row. With CSS you can style each row like you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidatePassKey(tb) {
  if (tb.TextLength >= 4)
    document.getElementById(tb.id + 1).focus();
  }
  if (tb.TextLength == 0 & tb.id !== 1){
       document.getElementById(tb.id - 1).focus();
  }
}
</script>

<input id="1" type="text" onchange="ValidatePassKey(this)" maxlength="4">
<input id="2" type="text" onchange="ValidatePassKey(this)" maxlength="4">
<input id="3" type="text" onchange="ValidatePassKey(this)" maxlength="4">
<input id="4" type="text" maxlength="4">
```

This just moves your cursor to the next text box once the text box you are currently in becomes full.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But what if I decide to delete some text in let's say id2 when there is text on id1 and id3? I need the text from id3 to get pushed to the previous line.

Comment: @bryan -- Add another condition, if length is 0 and input is not ID 1, focus on the previous.

Comment: @tymeJV focusing is one thing, moving text to the previous line on delete or pushing text forward to the next line with text added is a whole other monster I am trying to solve.

Comment: More condition checking, if the ID = 2 and length is 0 and ID 3's value is > 0, take the val from ID 3, put it into 2, and blank out 3's value

Comment: @tymeJV Seems really complicated. Because I'll have to move X amount of characters, not entire lines depending on what is added or deleted. I basically need it to act like a textarea.

Comment: It's going to be hard to do character lengths because different characters fill up different amount of spaces in a text box. It needs to be, once it is filled sort of thing @PixelReaper

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3 texboxes just for the lines, instead of that, why don't you use a textarea with an background-image?

Take a look at this: jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/Rh82q/

**updated**: jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/Rh82q/4/

Comment: I thought about that, but what do I do with the necessary indent on the first line with the text? @FelipeMiosso

Comment: If the indent is just for the first line. Add some &nbsp; into the textarea. I updated my fiddle.

Comment: It kind of needs to be fool proof. If the &nbsp;'s somehow get deleted, then my text would go over the label, if I can even figure out how to have the label. I need to emulate the picture above.

Comment: You are right. In fact, this looks like crap. I made a script that simulates something that might be usefull for you. I have a meeting right now but if you like I add comments to it later. :)

Comment: thank you for the help! This looks really interesting but it is way above my level of expertise to make it work the way I want it to

Comment: I'm using stackoverflow to practice english, so, if you need help with it you  may add me on gmail so we can talk about it :)

Comment: That would be awesome! what's your gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I think using many textareas or input fields are the wrong way to go.

Below you find an attempt to satisfy the indent, by adding spaces at the beginning if it doesn't exists. It also adds a <ul> element with many <li> elements to allow you to have line under the rows. It also scrolls the background if the textarea is filled with too much text.

Tested in Chrome30, FF25 and IE10 and intended as a proof of concept. If you are going to implement this, you should probably dynamically add as many <li> elements as you need. And the events should be bound properly.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/some/VXNp2/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div.mytext {
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
      }
      div.mytext > ul {
        position:absolute;
        top:5px;
        left:2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#f00;
        list-style:none;
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        z-index:0;
      }

      div.mytext >ul> li {
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;
        width:100%;
        height:19px;
      }

      div.mytext > ul,
      div.mytext > textarea {
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:20px;
        font-family:courier;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      div.mytext > textarea {
        position:relative;
        background:transparent;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
      function update(area) {
        if (!area.value.match(/^[ ]{8}/)) {
          area.value = '        ' +  area.value.replace(/^\s+/,"");
        }
        if (area.selectionStart < 8) {
          area.selectionStart = 8;
        }
      }

      function scroll(area) {
        area.parentElement.firstElementChild.scrollTop = area.scrollTop;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='mytext'>
      <ul>
          <li>Label:</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
      <textarea onkeydown='update(this)' onscroll='scroll(this)'></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Explanation:

- Create a div that has position:relative to set a reference for the child elements position.
- Create a ul that has position:absolute, with as many li-elements as necesary. The label goes into the first one, and the others has a no-breaking-space to allow styling.
- When a key i pressed a function is called that tests with a regexp if the value of the textarea starts with a certain number of spaces, and adds them if they are missing.
- If the textarea is scrolled another function is called that will scroll the background too.

**Disclaimer**: This is only a proof of concept and needs more work if it is going to be used in production.

Comment: This is definitely the closest to what I am looking for thank you! It definitely needs a lot of playing around but this should help me get into at least a solid direction. Any tips on getting that cursor to never go over the label?

Comment: @bryan. `element.selectionStart` (see updated code here and on jsfiddle).